# Is there any way to automate login process for all my domain computers using one account?

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

In our big network, there are many computers have lost trust relationship with the server and some of them have physical connection issue. I want to go to all computers, one by one, and log in by one account to check whether the computer will be able to log in or not. So how do I automate this process? 
by the way, I use Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you shouldn't be manually testing this on every computer, but you shouldn't automate it on the client side, either. Instead, you should be looking for a system NETLOGON [event ID 5722](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/810977/event-id-5722-is-logged-on-your-windows-server-based-domain-controller) on each domain controller to determine the clients with such issues. You could use this [PowerShell script by Joseph Moody](https://deployhappiness.com/finding-computers-with-a-broken-trust-relationship/) for that, too.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. Looking for others to guide me if they have ideas.

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach would be to use the `psexec` command line tool, which is available free of charge from the Microsoft web site.

Given a text file containing a list of computer names, and logged in with a domain account with administrative privilege on the computers in question, you would say something like,

```
for %n in (computers.txt) do psexec -s %i cmd /c echo ^%COMPUTERNAME^% >> alive.txt
```

That should generate a file `alive.txt` which you can compare to `computers.txt` or you could instead look for error messages.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. How about logging in computers? I mean is there any script where I can put username and password it will log in automatically after booting up?

Comment: The `psexec` command logs into the remote computer using your domain account.  That's quite sufficient to establish that the domain connection is working.